# How to change all images src attributes using HTML Agility?

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I need to convert all src attributes to point to the absolute path instead of relative path. I tried this using HTML Agility:

```
string html = "<body><div><img src=\"/folder/a.png\"/></div><div> <img src=\"/folder/b.png\"/></div></body>";
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
foreach (var node in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img"))
{
   var src = node.Attributes[@"src"].Value;
   if (src.StartsWith("/"))
      node.SetAttributeValue("//src", "www.abc.xyz" + src);
}
var newHtml = htmlDoc.Text;
```

But src attributes still points to the relative path!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `htmlDoc.DocumentNode.WriteTo()` method to reflect your changes in your original html

```
string html = "<body><div><img src=\"/folder/a.png\"/></div><div> <img src=\"/folder/b.png\"/></div></body>";
var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);
foreach (var node in htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//img"))
{
    var src = node.Attributes[@"src"].Value;
    if (src.StartsWith("/"))
        node.SetAttributeValue("src", "www.abc.xyz" + src);
}

var newHtml = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.WriteTo();
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Try once may it help you

Comment: @mshwf, view answer might be it help you :)